# create-react-app is not installng all dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

When I use npx create-react-app my-app first time in my ubuntu 22 version it install correctly but it is not installing all dependencies as I was installing in windows in my vs code I am using node 18 version which is LTS version and npm 8 version. But when I use npx create-react-app my-app it is showing me this warning when it is installed

Note: the project was bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of tools.
Please update to Node >=14 and npm >=6 to get supported tools in new projects.

[image]

Comment: How do you know that the modules are not installed?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete both `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

```
run npm i web-vitals --save-dev
run npm install
```

and then you can use `npm run build` and `npm start` again.

If these don't work, you can try

```
yarn cache clean
yarn install
```

and then  `npx create-react-app your-app`. Hope it helps!

Comment: it is working now. Thanks for solving this issue.